# ModelSim does not run until "$stop" command after editing my testbench

Tags: fpga, verilog, modelsim, testbench, libero

I keep running into this issue where my code stops running before the "@stop" command. This only occurs whenever I add code in Libero and then go back to ModelSim. When I go to simulate in ModelSim, my new code is showing up, however it is stopping early.

The only way I have been able to fix this so far is by creating an entirely new testbench each time which is very annoying when I should be able to just edit my existing one.

I've attached a screenshot from ModelSim so you can see what is going on.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Did you recompile the code after editing the code before running the simulation? If not, the editor may show the new code, but the simulator is using the old code, so the line numbers don't match up.

Comment: Yes, I right clicked on my code and hit recompile. I also right clicked and chose the update option but I still get the same result.